# Recyclerview not updating dataset and still shows old values

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

**RecyclerView Adapter update method**

```
public void updateList(List<Album> updatedList) {
     albums.clear();
     albums = new ArrayList<>(updatedList);
     for (int i = 0 ; i < albums.size(); i++) {
     Log.d(TAG, "updatedList values: " + albums.get(i).getAlbumName());
     }
     notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

After i pass my updated list to this method in my adapter and call `notifyDatasetChanged()` the updated values show up in the logcat.

**Logcat output shows the correct updated value**

```
AlbumAdapter: onBindViewHolder albumsList: 1967-1970 Disc 1
AlbumAdapter: onBindViewHolder albumsList: 1967-1970 Disc 1 
AlbumAdapter: onBindViewHolder albumsList: 1967-1970 Disc 1 
AlbumAdapter: onBindViewHolder albumsList: 1967-1970 Disc 1
```

And right after i switch back to this fragment the Recyclerview still shows the old value for some reason.

**Logcat output after switching back**

```
AlbumAdapter: onBindViewHolder albumsList: 1967-1970 Disc 2
AlbumAdapter: onBindViewHolder albumsList: 1967-1970 Disc 2
AlbumAdapter: onBindViewHolder albumsList: 1967-1970 Disc 2
AlbumAdapter: onBindViewHolder albumsList: 1967-1970 Disc 2
```

I even checked the value in my **updateList method** and there it shows **1967-1970 Disc 1**

**What i also tried**

```
public void updateList(List<Album> updatedList) {
         albums = updatedList;
         notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

But still the same problem.

**EDIT**

I noticed this only happens when i have alot of items.

If i have only 10 items it works fine without any problem but when i try with over 400+ items then it doesn't update the values.

**Recyclerview**

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_albums, container,false);

        recyclerViewAlbums = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewAlbums);

        if (getActivity() != null) {
            List<Album> albums = SongsLibrary.getInstance().getAlbums();
            if (!albums.isEmpty()){
                albumAdapter = new AlbumAdapter(getActivity(), albums, this, this);
                int noOfColumns = Utilities.calculateNoOfColumns(getActivity());
                final GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), noOfColumns);
                recyclerViewAlbums.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
                recyclerViewAlbums.setHasFixedSize(true);
                //recyclerViewAlbums.setItemViewCacheSize(20);
                recyclerViewAlbums.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                recyclerViewAlbums.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
                recyclerViewAlbums.setAdapter(albumAdapter);

                isInitRecyclerView = true;
                Log.i(TAG, "Albums loaded!");
            }else{
                isInitRecyclerView = false;
                Log.e(TAG, "No Albums found!");
            }
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "onCreateView called!");

        return rootView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of the problem.

Apparently my **ValueFilter** overwrites the new dataset i passed to my **updateList** method with old values.

**This is my ValueFilter for the SearchView**

```
private class ValueFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            String str = constraint.toString().toUpperCase();
            Log.e("constraint", str);
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (constraint.length() > 0) {
                List<Album> filterList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < albumsTemp.size(); i++) {
                    if ((albumsTemp.get(i).getAlbumName().toUpperCase())
                            .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {
                        Album album = albumsTemp.get(i);
                        filterList.add(album);
                    }
                }
                results.count = filterList.size();
                results.values = filterList;
            } else {
                results.count = albumsTemp.size();
                results.values = albumsTemp;
            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                //albums = (List<Album>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

After commenting `//albums = (List<Album>) results.values;` in **publishResults** it resolved my problem.